# ERC1155 _mintBatch() issue

Tags: solidity

Trying to create a function to mint a specific set of ERC1155 tokens but for some reason when executing no tokens are minted.  Code for mintSingle() works fine.  I've tried multiple ways of constructing the dynamic array that's required as an input to the OpenZeppelin ERC1155 contract function _mintBatch(address to, uint256[] ids, uint256[] amounts, bytes data), but nothing is working.  What am I doing wrong?  Thank you.

```
contract ExampleProject is ERC1155 {
    uint256 public constant ROWA = 0;
    uint256 public constant ROWBA = 30;

    constructor() public ERC1155("ipfs://Example/metadata/{id}.json") {

    }
        function mintRowA() 
            public 

             {
               uint256[] memory a = new uint256[](2);
               a[0] = ROWA;
               a[1] = ROWBA;

               uint256[] memory b = new uint256[](2);
               b[0] = 1;
               b[1] = 1;

                _mintBatch(msg.sender, a, b, "" );
        }

        function mintSingle()
        public
            {
                _mint(msg.sender, ROWBA, 1, "");
            }
}
```

Comment: have u find something

Comment: facing same issue

Comment: It seemed to be an issue with Etherscan.  If you use the balanceOf function to check your account for the token, you'll see the ERC1155 tokens do get minted with _mintBatch, but ES isn't showing the transfer like it does for single mint.  Been meaning to put a ticket in to ES to remedy this.

Comment: in opensea also i am not able to see any tokens so i think there is some deeper issue.